# Android - Different bytecode of text file for release build

Tags: android, build, release, android-assets

I am having problem with different byte representation of my file in assets folder for release build. Some library that I am using is providing licence file that i have included to assets. In debug build the library accepts the licence file but for release build the exception is raised.

When I export that file from release apk and look at text representation, no difference is there but when I look at hex representation it differs. Here is a few bytes for comparision:

Original

```
0d23 230a 4420 204f 4e5f 544f 205f 4f4d
4944 5946 5420 4948 2053 4946 454c 0d21
230a 0a0d 2023 754d 6966 206e 6d47 4862
```

Release

```
0a23 2023 4f44 5f20 4f4e 5f54 4d20 444f
4649 2059 4854 5349 4620 4c49 2145 230a
230a 4d20 6675 6e69 4720 626d 2048 694c
```

Comment: Please show the file and your export function and hex code.

Comment: Well I cant show the file for obvious reason (its license file) and i dont know what you mean by export function, i dont have any .. I am just passing stream with opened licence file to some api that the library sdk has

Comment: `When I export that file from release apk`. And how are you converting to hex?

Comment: Well with export i mean copy from apk zip. And I am using hexdump for hex comparision

Comment: How does one copy from apk.zip? On what are yoy using a hexdump? And how? Very vague all. I you don't come to the point with showing code i cannot help you.

Comment: Well, as you may know, apk is just another extension of zip ;) so when you downlaod apk, opens it with winzip, you can see files .. so i grab a file in assets folder and extract it to my hard drive, get it? And on my hard drive, i am using hexdump for looking at the license file. I dont know how more clearly say it. There is no code needed, I am talking about building ..

Comment: That was finally a clear explanation. You should have told that right from the start. But what you do makes no sense. You should add code to your app to inspect the file at runtime from the assets folder. Or copy from assets to file system. Once on the file system you can connect your device with your pc and inspect the 'exported' file. Or install a hexdump app on your device to inspect the file.